# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency exception when

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting `UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency exception` when assigning,

```
txtFieldDelegate.view = self.view;  
txtFirstName.delegate = txtFieldDelegate;
txtLastName.delegate = txtFieldDelegate;
```

I am having text field delegate methods in some other class and creating objects for the text field delegate class to use the same. 
Please provide suggestions to resolve this..

Comment: What are `txtFieldDelegate` and `self` in your code?

Comment: self represents the current view controller. txtFieldDelegate is the object of a class which imports UITextFieldDelegate protocol and implements all textfield related delegate methods implementation.

Comment: And txtFieldDelegate.view is your own property? And generally what this assignment is for?

Answer (score 1):

This view controller was inheriting a class which inherits UIViewController. The inherited class's inheritance is changed as NSObject. 
Instead of TheClass: UIViewController, it was changed as
TheClass:NSObject

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SomeOtherClassViewController *txtFieldDelegateVC = [[SomeOtherClassViewController alloc] init]; 
txtFirstName.delegate = txtFieldDelegateVC;
txtLastName.delegate = txtFieldDelegateVC;
```

Comment: This assignment provides a view to perform text field delegate method's actions. After this assignment delegate class for all the textfields in the page is assigned as txtFieldDelegate class.                                                 // Assigning text field delegates
    
    txtFirstName.delegate = txtFieldDelegate;
    txtLastName.delegate = txtFieldDelegate;